# How to check if the login failed

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient

The following code has been generated by Fiddler, and is called in the button_Click event.

```
 //Create request to URL.
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://forums.codeguru.com/login.php?do=login");

 //Set request headers.
 request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";
 request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
 request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.5");
 request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
 request.Referer = "http://forums.codeguru.com/";
 request.KeepAlive = false;
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

 //Set request method
 request.Method = "POST";

 // Disable 'Expect: 100-continue' behavior. More info: http://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

 //Set request body.

 **// Fail**
  string body = @"vb_login_username=**userid**&vb_login_password=&vb_login_password_hint=Password&s=&securitytoken=guest&do=login&vb_login_md5password=a35cef11bdd55e36423f8d3b1ed69dea&vb_login_md5password_utf=a35cef11bdd55e36423f8d3b1ed69dea";

  byte[] postBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
  request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
  Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
  stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
  stream.Close();

 //Get response to request.
 response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

 var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
 string srcString = reader.ReadToEnd();

 }
 catch (WebException e)
 {
            //ProtocolError indicates a valid HTTP response, but with a non-200 status code (e.g. 304 Not Modified, 404 Not Found)
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            else return false;
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
            if (response != null) response.Close();
            return false;
 }

return true;
```

}

Code in the button_Click event

```
       HttpWebResponse response;

        if (Request_forums_codeguru_com(out response))
        {
            //Success, possibly use response.

            HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;

            // Status is alway OK

            response.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Succesful login");

        }
        else
        {
            //Failure, cannot use response.

            MessageBox.Show("Unsuccesful login");
        }
```

But even if I enter the wrong password, I get HttpStatus as OK. How do I check for the login failure.

In the final stage, I shall be receiving data from a Python server, so the above is just a test.

Edit :

When the user enters a wrong user id / password combination he/she gets to see the following :-

[image: Wrong User id / Password combination]

Answer (score 1):

With the code above, you're basically mimic-ing browser behaviour. The website necessarily return an errored HTTPStatus simply because you got the password wrong - look at how the target website handles a wrong password.

If you try to access a secured page that's when you may get the Unauthorised access error and redirected to the log in screen. Depending on how the site is set up.

There's a couple of possibilities:

1. Log in, and then try and access a secures page, check for
   non-authorised access error or page text returned in the response
2. Check the url of the response - has it changed to the url you expect
   for a successful login?
3. Check the text of the response and look for
   something like "wrong password", "invalid password" etc.

Ultimately, there's no scalable or uniform way of doing this apart from maybe option 2. You'll be writing site-specific code.